# silent argument checking or yelling about it?

Tags: java

we have a dicussion about that method -

```
public static AbstractAttribute getAttribute(List<AbstractAttribute> attributes, String name) {
    if ((attributes != null) && (name != null) && !name.trim().isEmpty()) {
        for (AbstractAttribute attribute : attributes) {
            if (attribute.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                return attribute;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Is that priori right or not?
IMO there must be checking arguments logic with some exceptions to prevent the "client" wrong using.
So that u must review your code that uses this method in case of error instead of thinking that everything is ok and "list = null" returns the "null" as it does not contain some given key even if list is null though

===========Updated====
there exist 4 general cases for calling that method -

```
getAttribute(null,null); // returns null
getAttribute(list,null); // returns null
getAttribute(null,name); // returns null
getAttribute(list,name); //  may return null if not found
```

all of them may return null, so how client can understand the difference between different type of calls? He might have made mistake calling method with null argument - and he recieved the null result as if everything ok and attribute just not found in list, but it CANT be found at all.
Hmm... don't know, but i think there must be arg checking...

Comment: There is no doubt about the case where `attributes` or `name` is `null` -- you should `throw new IllegalArgumentException("the list should not be null")` with a different message for `name == null`. However, if the name is not found within the list then there is some room for a design decision based on your specific application and you could decide to return `null` instead of throwing an exception. Of course, you must document the decision in the JavaDoc.

Comment: IMHO it depends on design. To do argument checking in a paranoic way could even add performance penalties and you may be checking conditions that may never happen. If the arguments are statically (by a developer) provided or developer-controlled after being gathered elsewhere, then a note in the docs is better than a check in the code. In this way the developer must check the data before calling your method.

Comment: @watery yes, if the same person/team is consuming the API and knows that the argument will never be null then it should not be checked. my comments were intended for the case where you are offering an API to another team or to a development community (e. g. java sdk api's).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you *should* ask yourself is, which is more useful to a developer?

```
AbstractAttribute a = getAttribute(null, "name");

a.something(); // Oh no, null pointer.
```

or

```
AbstractAttribute a = getAttribute(null, "name"); // Oh no, invalid argument exception.
```

Your `Exception` should **ALWAYS** be as close to the actual problem as possible. If they have a problem with their arguments that fatally interrupts the functionality of the method, then throw an exception! The developer needs to know their mistake and the duty falls to you to make sure it's as clear as possible.

**Edit**

Yes, you're on the right lines. Your message needs to be specific.

```
public Object myFunction(String something, String somethingElse) {
    // First option - Not so good.
    if(something == null || somethingElse == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid parameters. Can not be null");
    }

    // Second option - much better.

    if(something == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Something can not be null");
    }

    if(somethingElse == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Something else can not be null");
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 and edited your example the way i thought you intended it. (also voted to reopen this question)

Comment: Yes, thank you for correcting the mistake!

Comment: just can't get why the method must\may silently search attribute in the null-list at all. You must have been wrong putting null into args, and you probably may not find your mistake as fast as it could be in case of exception.

Comment: For me it's like a divide by zero then catch error and do nothing instead of finding bug in your logic and fixing it.

Comment: Christopher, in all cases it's possible to get null, even if all args non-null...

Comment: Sorry I don't understand? If a value provided is null it will throw an illegal argument exception.

Comment: =) I meant, in your first case, even if you provides non-null arguments you may recieve a null as returned value - meaning that attribute is not found, so that you must always check that value on null. But in case of passing there null-args - you also recieve null - there is no any difference, lol. And i think such behavior is wrong... See my first post, i've updated it... Thanks for answering